# How to compile/build a TypeScript library that uses no NodeJS API/Module dependency to support browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, compilation, shared-libraries

I wrote a few code that use plain browser Javascript APIs only and can be run well within browser HTML (served by IIS Server or Chrome Extensions). Now I want to contribute to the community by writing a library I have not seen on the market yet. However looking at current solutions, I am at loss at how a project is even built (WebPack/Browserify etc). A side note: I never actually work with NodeJS/NPM before.

For example I have this TypeScript project with the main file `AwesomeClass.ts` like this:

```
import { Helper1 } from "./Helper1.js";
import { Helper2 } from "./Helper2.js";

export class AwesomeClass {
    doSomething() {
        new Helper1().doSomething();
        new Helper2().doSomething();
    }
}
```

When built with `tsc` (I use VS Code as IDE), I can perfectly put this inside an Javascript module and browser can run it.

```
import { AwesomeClass } from "./AwesomeClass.js";

// Do something with AwesomeClass
```

So my question is, how do I build and distribute `AwesomeClass`? Maybe no NPM needed, but from a CDN? Ideally, I think somehow I should have the following output in a `dist` folder and developer can refer them either by hosting the files by themselves or use a CDN:

- `awesomeclass.js`: For those who want to just use `AwesomeClass` without module feature (I think it's called UMD?). I.e. expose the `AwesomeClass` to global scope.
- `awesomeclass.es6.js`: For those who want to use `AwesomeClass` by using `import` statement, like `import { AwesomeClass } from "https://cdn.example.com/awesomeclass.es6.js";`. I like this approach best and want to use this.
- I should have something like `awesomeclass.d.ts` so those using TypeScript can use it. This one is especially tricky because so far I still don't understand how to make it work for 2nd scenario. TypeScript cannot get the type from an import statement from Javascript, and even ignoring that, I cannot get any typing for `import` statements.

In all cases, I would rather have only one `js`/`ts` file packed together if possible but not a deal breaker if I cannot (i.e. user will have to download `Helper1.js` and `Helper2.js` as well if I cannot).

Here's my current `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ES2020",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a lot of things you're asking and each of them have several answers so I'll try to provide you with a bit of an overview of your options.

**Compiling everything to a single file**

One of the things you asked is how you can compile everything to a single file.  You can do that in 2 different ways, either using webpack to bundle it for client or using typescript directly.

- If you use typescript you have to set `outFile` to a specific file, in which case it will compile everything to that file, however you can only do that if your `module` is also set to amd or system, both of which are not ideal.  While this works it's something I'd suggest you don't use.
- Instead you should use webpack to bundle all your stuff with the `output` option, in which case webpack will use `ts-loader` to invoke typescript for you, compile your stuff and bundle it into a single file.

You should also note here that this is only applicable if you actually want to serve it through web and not if you're building a library.  If you're building an npm package that you're planning on letting people install with something like `npx packageName` so that you can use it like `import somePackage from some-package`, then you should be compiling your stuff to a `/lib` directory into normal javascript and just let them import it as javascript.  There's no reason for why you should provide them with the original typescript in that case.

**How to build and distribute it**

It really depends on what exactly you're building and how it'll be used, however overall you have 2 main options.

- You can either host it somewhere on some server with a domain of your choice so that people can download it.  Or you can put it anywhere like a normal git repo where people can download it.  In this case you'll have to compile it with webpack yourself, upload it yourself and then just share the link with people i.e. `https://example.com/downloads/awesome`.  Alternatively you can use webpack to render it server side and expose an API to people that they can call in order to get your code, then it will deliver the bundled javascript to them once they call the API i.e. `https://api.example.com/awesome` which will hit your API with a GET request, which will route to `awesome` and then you invoke webpack's compiler to bundle your code server side.
- Your other option is to build your package like normal, compile it and then use the official npm registry to host your npm package.  Using this option will allow people to `npx package` or `npm i package` on your code and also allow them to use it like `import awesome from 'awesome'`.  If you go this route then using webpack isn't necessary, or it depends, because people using it will import it into their own project and build it into their own webpack setup and bundle if required.  In this case all you have to do is compile your typescript to something like a `/lib` and allow them to install and import it.

From the things that you're asking/saying it seems to me that you're trying to create an npm package, for that all you need is to create the package, compile your typescript, set up an account on npm and push your package to their registry, from where you can let anyone install it.  For this you also shouldn't care at all about compiling all your code to a single file because it doesn't matter, if they use `import awesome from 'awesome'` then that file can again import anything else inside your own package and they wouldn't know it.  You can just `tsc` your code to an output directory and let them know which is the default export for that package.

If your code has to run in browser then I don't believe just using typescript will be enough, in that case you'll have to use webpack, you might also need babel if you need to support older browsers and polyfills, which is something you can add to webpack, then you'll use webpack to compile your bundle.  Webpack will then invoke typescript, through ts-loader, which will compile and bundle your code for you ready for web.  In this case you'll still need to push this code to the npm registry as a package so others can use it.

The choice between those options is entirely dependent on what it is and who's going to use it and how.

Comment: Thanks for great details! I will check them out today and see how best to setup my build flow. I think my main distribution channel would be GitHub and CDN since my main concern is for web developer to be able to do `import { AwesomeClass } from "https://cdn.example.com/awesomeclass.min.js"`. Won't hurt if I support NPM as well I guess just hope I don't mess up my setup too much trying to support every option.

Comment: Importing from a URL is also okay if you want to host it yourself.  The benefit to me with npm is caching the packages, I don't have enough data to install them over and over, if they're always downloaded from a URL then it will use a lot more data (I don't think it's being cached then).  You'd also lose out on being able to use things like npm-link.  But those aren't major concerns, if it works for you then you can just import it directly from the URL.  You can compile it with webpack and push it to both your CDN and the npm registry and have the best of both.

Comment: One major drawback of using URL that you should also consider is
upgrade/downgrade your dependencies in the project will be hard if the developer uses it from the URL.
They need to search for the package name and replace the version of your package. 

https://cdn.example.com/v1/awesomeclass.min.js https://cdn.example.com/v2/awesomeclass.min.js

If you don't have a version in the URL then, it will be a very bad experience if you introduce breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the core requirements in the `tscongfig.json` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es6", "es2020.promise", "dom", "es2020"],
        "declaration": true,
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2020"
    }
}
```

While to pack everything in just one file, I think you have to use something like `webpack`; but I don't know enough this topic to help you on that, sorry.